# Nested entity not being saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following method that saves an `EmailTemplate`.  Based on the ID of a dropdown it populates the `EmailAccount` as the foreign entity property.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EmailAccountId, EmailTemplate")] EmailTemplateViewModel emailTemplateViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (emailTemplateViewModel.EmailAccountId > 0)
        {
            emailTemplateViewModel.EmailTemplate.EmailAccount = db.EmailAccounts.Find(emailTemplateViewModel.EmailAccountId);
        }
        db.Entry(emailTemplateViewModel.EmailTemplate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(emailTemplateViewModel);
}
```

Everything in the `EmailTemplate` saves fine apart from `EmailAccount`.  In debugger I can see that the property is populated before `db.SaveChanges()` is called.

I am setting the entity state to `EntityState.Modified` but it's not picking up the foreign property.

I tried adding:

```
db.Entry(emailTemplateViewModel.EmailTemplate.EmailAccount).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But this didn't work.  How do I tell EntityFramework that it needs to save the nested entity?

Edit:

As requested

```
public class EmailTemplateViewModel
{
    public List<EmailAccount> EmailAccounts { get; set; }
    public EmailTemplate EmailTemplate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Account")]
    public int EmailAccountId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmailAccountsList
    {
        get
        {
            var allEmails = EmailAccounts.Select(e => new SelectListItem { Value = e.ID.ToString(), Text = e.Email });

            return DefaultEmailAccountList.Concat(allEmails);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DefaultEmailAccountList
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "-1", 
                Text = "Select Email Account"
            }, count: 1);
        }
    }
}

public class EmailTemplate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }

    public string TitleTemplate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string BodyTemplate { get; set; }

    public virtual EmailAccount EmailAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post your models, both the main entity and the referenced one.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: How you specify (configure) the mapping between your `EmailTemplate` and `Account`. I can see only `public virtual EmailAccount EmailAccount { get; set; }` without a foreign key. Do you use fluent api n your `OnModelCreating` method?

Comment: I only use fluent api on many-to-many relationships as EF automatically detects one to many when you specify public virtual property.  It just has problems with many-to-many.  I am only interested in knowing what email accounts are associated with email templates. I don't care about finding all templates from an email account.

Comment: You need to add the `public int EmailAccountId { get; set; }` to your `EmailTemplate` then configure the mapping. EF will know when to add or update the referenced accout.

Comment: no, this wasn't the case.  It was because I was modifying it before i attached it

Answer (score 0):

I was modifying before I attached so the change wasn't tracked.

This works

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(emailTemplateViewModel.EmailTemplate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            if (emailTemplateViewModel.EmailAccountId > 0)
            {
                emailTemplateViewModel.EmailTemplate.EmailAccount = db.EmailAccounts.Find(emailTemplateViewModel.EmailAccountId);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(emailTemplateViewModel);
```